How do I check for the last repair date?
Can someone let me know, How to check last repair date in Cassandra

Yes, you can check the repair_history table in the system_distributed keyspace:
aaron@cqlsh:system_distributed> use system_distributed;
aaron@cqlsh:system_distributed> SELECT * FROm repair_history LIMIT 2;

 keyspace_name | columnfamily_name       | id                                   | coordinator | coordinator_port | exception_message | exception_stacktrace | finished_at                     | parent_id                            | participants                  | participants_v2                         | range_begin          | range_end            | started_at                      | status
---------------+-------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+------------------+-------------------+----------------------+---------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+---------------------------------+---------
     reaper_db | schema_migration_leader | 32990010-50e7-11ef-a1ea-630aa24d77a7 |  10.116.8.9 |             7000 |              null |                 null | 2024-08-02 10:52:19.784000-0500 | 328a0bf0-50e7-11ef-a1ea-630aa24d77a7 | {'10.116.10.6', '10.116.9.7'} | {'10.116.10.6:7000', '10.116.9.7:7000'} |  8398343353019649468 |  8482078889601787379 | 2024-08-02 10:52:18.886000-0500 | SUCCESS
     reaper_db | schema_migration_leader | 44a18c00-50e7-11ef-b0cb-b357c675bc79 |  10.116.9.7 |             7000 |              null |                 null | 2024-08-02 10:52:49.496000-0500 | 4497c800-50e7-11ef-b0cb-b357c675bc79 | {'10.116.10.6', '10.116.8.9'} | {'10.116.10.6:7000', '10.116.8.9:7000'} |   819786040769076981 |   905264258080445391 | 2024-08-02 10:52:49.117000-0500 | SUCCESS

Look for the finished_at column to determine when the repairs for specific tables have completed.

Just to add to @Aaron's response, you might find that the entries in the system_distributed.repair_history table might be too "noisy" since it contains multiple entries (by repair parent_id) of each individual sub-range repairs called by a parent repair thread.
As an alternative, check the entries in the system_distributed.parent_repair_history table. This table contains the top-level parent_id for repairs which will tell you when the parent repair thread completed, not the completion time of the individual [child] sub-range repairs. Cheers!
